# What is the gradient of a vector field?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

> What is the gradient of a vector field? Express and write it mathematically. Also, physically interpret it.

---

From what I know, the gradient of a vector field is zero because it is only possible for scalar field. Even if it is possible, how can I write it mathematically and what is its physical interpretation?

Comment: See the questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754710/finding-the-gradient-of-a-tensor-field) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156880/what-does-it-mean-to-take-the-gradient-of-a-vector-field?rq=1) or the wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Gradient_of_a_vector_field).